# ToC: How to no-indent the second line of large entries?

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, tocloft

ToC: How to no-indent the second line of large entries?

I'm using the `scrreprt` class, typesetting a book with only 120mm of paperwidth.

Comment: Are you using `tocloft` or `tocstyle`? Both are ToC-customizing packages, and they are incompatible with each other.

Comment: I known that in tocloft, there's a \cftXindent, to controls the indentation of an entry from the left margin, and that can be changed using \setlength, but i don't know where to put that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I don't like dropping the indentation, but here you go. (`1.5em` is only a guess.)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\hspace{1.5em}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut
    purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!. This is exactly what i need. In fact, i keep the indentation for sections, so your solution (on chapters, i see) provides me a balanced solution. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Steve: You're welcome -- and don't forget to upvote and accept my answer. ;-)