# How to remove hanging indent in Table Of Contents - Memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

How to no-indent the second line of large TOC entries in memoir class?

I found a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28343/toc-how-to-no-indent-the-second-line-of-large-entries) using toсloft, but I can not find how to do it in a memoir.

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no really supported out of the box, but can be achieved via

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\l@chapapp}{\advance\memRTLleftskip\@tempdima}%
 {}%                       replace with nothing
 {\typeout{patched ok}}%   went ok
 {\typeout{patch failed}}% went bad
\makeatother
```

(only tested on chapters)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to achieve the same result on sections and subsections?

Comment: It works, (`\l@section` etc), but you'll have to change the `\cftTYPEindent` as well. I would ask you to reconsider using a design like this. It is not particularly readable for the reader.